Unable to create more than 127 windows/terminals in tmux
I am using tmux on macOS. As the number of repos that I am working with increases, the number of tmux windows increases as well. Just yesterday, I run into the issue that I am not able to open more than 127 tmux windows which breaks my whole workflow.
create window failed: fork failed: Too many open files
can't find window: 128
can't find window: 128

The workaround that I found does not work
sudo sysctl -w kern.tty.ptmx_max=511

What do I need to configure to open more than 127 windows in tmux?

Increasing the number of open files increases the limit:
ulimit -n 1024

